# Operator precedence prefix conversion - Scheme

Tags: scheme, prefix, infix-notation, operator-precedence

I am writing a function that takes a quoted arithmetic infix expression involving numbers, variables, and operators and converts it to prefix notation.

For example:

```
 (infix->prefix '(2 + 3 * x ^ 5 + a))
```

would evaluate to

```
(+ 2 (+ (* 3 (^ x 5)) a))
```

or

```
(+ (+ 2 (* 3 (^ x 5))) a)
```

In order of precedence we have: +,-,*,/, and  ^.

This is what I have so far

```
 (define (infix->prefix lst) 
   (if (list? lst)
   (if (null? (cdr lst))
      (car lst)
      (list (cadr lst)
            (infix->prefix (car lst))
            (infix->prefix (cddr lst)))
      )
   lst)
  )
```

This gives the correct prefix notation but with no precedence. It evaluates to

```
(+ 2 (* 3 (^ x (+ 5 a))))
```

Which is the right order but the parenthesis are off because of the precedence. I have done some research and am having a hard time figuring out how to add it.

Any feedback or suggestions on how to refactor my code would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this is the problem of parsing. There are *lots* of different ways of tackling it, but none of them are trivial, except for fully-parenthesized. But presumably the whole point of this was to use infix without parentheses.

If I was trying to implement this quickly, I would use one of the existing parser packages for Racket; maybe [parsack](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parsack/index.html?q=parse) or [ragg](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ragg/index.html) or the more traditional [parser-tools](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/index.html?q=parser-tools).

Comment: Thank you! The assignment is for class and I don't think we can use racket but i will look into it for further assistance.

Comment: If it's for a class, your instructor is surely steering you toward a particular parsing technique... ?

Comment: ... or maybe she or he just wants you to break it up using the operators with lowest precedence first, and then subdivide until you get a complete tree? Either way, I'm guessing that a particular strategy was described in the assignment.

Comment: Yes. I made a function to check for precedence. I just am having issues with where to apply that function and how. If I have new code, where can I add that? As an edit? New to this.